# Find probability that for $300$ randomnly chosen cars, more than $5$ of these cars will be exceeding the speed limit by more than $20$ miles per hour.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution

I am solving past papers of my probability course. I don't have answer key to them. Here is the question I came across along with my approach. I think my approach is okay, but I am not confident. Kindly guide me if there is some correction needed. Thanks.

**STATEMENT:** An automated radar gun is placed on a road to record the speed of the cars passing by. The automated radar gun records $0.41$% of the cars going more than $20$ miles per hour above the speed limit. Assume the number of cars going more than $20$ miles above the speed limit has a Poisson distribution.

**QUESTION:** Find the value of paramter $\lambda$, mean & variance. In the last, calculate the probability that for $300$ randomnly chosen cars, more than $5$ of these cars will be exceeding the speed limit by more than $20$ miles per hour.

**MY WORKING:**

Let the $p$ denote the success rate of automated radar gun recording speed of the cars, then we are given that $p=0.41$, since the sample size $n=300$ is the big number and $p$ is smaller we can use poisson distribution to solve the problem (which we are already told to do in the statement part). Let $X$ denote poisson random variable then:

So in the case of approximating binomial distribution through poisson, we know that:  $\lambda=np=300\times0.41=123$

Since mean & variance of poisson distribution are same, namely $\lambda$ we have:

$\lambda=123$,

mean=$\lambda=123$,

variance=$\lambda=123$

As for the last part, the probability that more than $5$ cars will be exceeding limit can be found as:

$P(X>5)=1-P(X\leq4)$ (which can be found by using poisson distribution with $\lambda=123$)

Comment: $.41\%$ is not a probability of $.41$, not even close.

Comment: Should say:  the problem is very poorly phrased.  I am guessing that it means that we are to assume that, on average, $.41\%$ of passing cars exceed the threshold (I don't understand the emphasis on the radar gun; it makes it appear that the gun only picks up a fraction of the speeders).

Comment: Indeed they are poorly phrased but I have to do them to perform well in upcoming exam. It's the task our instructor has assigned to the whole class. If 0.41% isn't the probability of 0.41, the what is it? I thought it is the probability given in percentage that's all.

Comment: Also is my rest of the approach okay?

Comment: there is a  *big* difference between percent and decimal.  $1\%$ is not a probability of $1$, right?  And $50\%$ really can't be a probability of $50$.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right. I did make a mistake in there.

Comment: The key point is that you should think about the numbers as you use them, don't calculate blindly.  You should know that $.41\%$ is a very small percent, so you couldn't possible expect nearly half of all cases to meet that threshold.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very poorly phrased, as it could be interpreted 2 ways:

- The radar gun catches $0.41\%$ of people going more than 20 over the limit (illogical but how it reads)
- Or more likely the gun measures the speed of every car and registers that $0.41\%$ of people are 20 or more over the limit

I will assume the latter of these as it makes more sense. Your approach is correct although notice that:
$$0.41\%=\frac{0.41}{100}=0.0041$$
and so we should get:
$$\lambda=np=300\times 0.0041=1.23$$
which makes a lot more sense as we know $\lambda<20$. Through the fact that less than $100\%$ are more than 20 over the limit